# Top Level menu item in dropdown

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu made fully in CSS (no JS). I'd like the top level menu item to stay highlighted when I hover on its dropdown menus but I can't figure out how.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about: when you place your cursor on the dropdown, the top level item goes back to default color...

Could anyone help with that? Is there a rule in CSS that would fix that?

Here is the CSS:

```
nav {
    z-index: 10001;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-align: center
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none
}
#topmenu {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    left: 2%
}
nav ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block
}
nav ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s linear,visibility .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear,visibility .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s linear,visibility .3s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s linear,visibility .3s linear
}
nav ul ul li: last-child {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #afafaf
}
nav ul li a: hover {
    padding: 13px 20px;
    color: green
}
nav ul ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #afafaf;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee 0,#d4d4d4 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#eee 0,#d4d4d4 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#eee 0,#d4d4d4 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#eee 0,#d4d4d4 100%);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #ccc;
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ccc,Direction=134,Strength=5);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eeeeee',endColorstr='#d4d4d4')
}
nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 13px 20px;
    color: #063058
}
nav ul li: hover>ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -webkit-opacity: 1
}
nav ul li {
    float: left
}
#topmenu li a: hover {
    color: #fff
}
#topmenu li a: hover {
    color: green;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee 0,#d4d4d4 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#eee 0,#d4d4d4 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#eee 0,#d4d4d4 100%);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #ccc;
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ccc,Direction=134,Strength=5);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eeeeee',endColorstr='#d4d4d4')
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    color: white
}
nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is missing. Try setting up a working example of your in something like jsfiddle and i will be happy to demonstrate how it's done. Shouldn't be to hard

Comment: I tried (http://jsfiddle.net/qpGc8/), but it doesn't work in jsfiddle, which is why I gave a direct url to the website :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
#topmenu li:hover a {
    background: linear-gradient(#EEEEEE 0px, #D4D4D4 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #CCCCCC inset;
    color: green;
}
```

I`ve just copied your code there.

Comment: This does work, thanks -- just gotta fix the dropdown item's color when hovering

Comment: You guys are awesome, thanks for the help -- This had been bugging me for weeks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't get your website to load so i've just done this fiddle for you with lots of comments expalaining the CSS
I have done this fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/PknRT/

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
```